# J-query loop issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I have what is supposed to be a simple jquery delayed image loop

[The fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/caedanlavender/aH5ts/)

I have checked my syntax and i do not know why it refuses to work.

All the css and code seems to be correct.

Here is the function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.doTimeout('loop', 500, function () {
    //changes the background of img2 to 'i' in 'sequence'
    $(".img2").css('background', 'url(' + sequence[i] + ')');
    //increments 'i' for the next image
    i++;
    //toggles the class 
    $("img1").toggleClass("img2");
    //changes the the background of img1 to 'i' in 'sequence' ready for when class is toggled again
    $(".img1").css('background', 'url(' + sequence[i] + ')');
    //toggles the class
    $("img2").toggleClass("img1");
    //increments 'i; for the next change
    i++;
    //restarts the loop if i is equal to the sequence length
    if (i === sequence.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
});
```

toggleclass has to be there because i intend to later add css3 transitions which will make each image fade in

Can someone help, please!

Comment: sorry, the link was broken, i have fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `True` in your callback for the loop to happen again, it is mentioned in the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Start a polling loop with an id of 'loop' and a counter.
  $.doTimeout('loop', 500, function(){
     
      $('.img1').css('background', 'url(' + sequence[i] + ')');
      i++;
      return true;
  });
});
```

Another issue is that your loop will break as your array will go **out of bounds** as you keep incrementing, instead use `Array.shift` to get the first element out of array and `push` it back to the end of the array. With this elements in the array will go in a cycle, you dont have to maintain a counter and reset it etc...

Right way to do it is:-

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZDSR/)

```
var sequence = ["http://goo.gl/u4QHd",
    "http://goo.gl/s5tmq",
    "http://goo.gl/MMsQ6",
    "http://goo.gl/dtEYw"];

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Start a polling loop with an id of 'loop' and a counter.
  $.doTimeout('loop', 500, function(){
     var url = sequence.shift(); //Remove the first element out of the array
      sequence.push(url); //push it to the end of the array. probably you can put it after the next statement.
      $('#img1').css('background', 'url(' + sequence[0] + ')');//get the first item from the array. this will always be the next one to previous cycle.
      return true;
  });
});
```

Comment: can you explain what .shift and .push is doing in your script?

Comment: Updated my answer.. Does it make sense?

Comment: @CaedanLavender The documentation is free for everyone: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: @bažmegakapa Thanks... @@CaedanLavender Hope you got it now...

Comment: @CaedanLavender Please consider marking as answer if this resolved your issue and got your questions answered...

Comment: Alright, your answer has made the delay work perfectly, however the next part of the problem is that when it toggles class to the other div the css3 transistions are not working. The fiddle should have been updated but just in case here is the:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/caedanlavender/XTkB3/)